# Sentry SDK dotnet core not using IUserFactory

Tags: c#, .net-core, sentry

I am trying to customize the way that we show the user for a sentry event.

My appsettings is like so:

```
"Sentry": {
    "DSN": "...",
    "IncludeRequestPayload": true,
    "SendDefaultPii": true,
    "MinimumBreadcrumbLevel": "Debug",
    "MinimumEventLevel": "Warning",
    "AttachStackTrace": true,
    "Debug": true,
    "DiagnosticsLevel": "Error"
  },
```

I register the Factory as a singleton (I've also tried transient too)
`services.AddSingleton<Sentry.AspNetCore.IUserFactory, MySentryUserFactory>();`

In my startup, I call UseSentry like so:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) => ...)
        .UseKestrel(options => ...)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseSentry()
        .Build().Run();
}
```

In the MySentryUserFactory, I haven't been seeing its effects so I put a Console.WriteLine at the very top:

```
public User Create(HttpContext context)
{
  Console.WriteLine("------------------- I am using the custom userfactory");
  ...
}
```

So I test it by manually calling the SentrySdk:

```
Exception e = new Exception("blah");
SentrySdk.CaptureException(e);
```

But when I run it, I see no print output statement in the console. Then when I go to sentry dashboard, I see the error event that I'm testing with and the user is not shown (didn't do what the IUserFactory was set up to do).

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to opt-in to capture user identifiable information which based on your configuration you did.

A working sample is (assumes a DSN is available: like appsettings.json or environment variable):

```
public class Program : IUserFactory
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices(s => s.AddSingleton<IUserFactory, Program>())
            .UseSentry(o => o.SendDefaultPii = true)
            .Configure(a => a.Use( (context, next) => throw null))
            .Build()
            .Run();

    public User Create(HttpContext context) => new User {Id = "works"};
}
```

Upon [reviewing the code in Sentry's .NET SDK](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/blob/5a01c5b6371571884f7fa030b086615b4621bb87/src/Sentry.AspNetCore/ScopeExtensions.cs#L33-L40):

```
if (options?.SendDefaultPii == true && !scope.HasUser())
{
    var userFactory = context.RequestServices?.GetService<IUserFactory>();
    if (userFactory != null)
    {
        scope.User = userFactory.Create(context);
    }
}
```

I realize that maybe you already have a user set in the scope and for that reason the factory is not being resolved and called?

You can verify that with a callback:

```
.UseSentry(o =>
{
    o.BeforeSend = @event =>
    {
        if (@event.HasUser())
        {
            // ...
            @event.User = new User();
        }

        return @event;
    };
})
```

Or with an event processor which can be registered with DI and take dependencies:

```
public class UserEventProcessor : ISentryEventProcessor
{
    private readonly IUserFactory _userFactory;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

    public UserEventProcessor(IUserFactory userFactory, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _userFactory = userFactory;
        _accessor = accessor;
    }

    public SentryEvent Process(SentryEvent @event)
    {
        @event.User = _userFactory.Create(_accessor.HttpContext);
        return @event;
    }
}

// and register:
services.ConfigureServices(s => s.AddScoped<ISentryEventProcessor, UserEventProcessor>())
```

Comment: When instrumenting Sentry using OpenTelemetry the UserFactory doesn't seem to get called.

Comment: Can you please raise a ticket for the SDK maintainers? https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet

Comment: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/issues/2616 - Thanks Bruno